# Руссификация календаря Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

Как русифицировать календарь?

```
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1324977642" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico?1324977642" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://demo.qloapps.com/themes/hotel-reservation-theme/cache/v_4_9b61da8e0eb746405f309406327e19e3_all.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12"> <label class="control-label" for="check_in_time" >Check In Time</label>
            <div class="input-group" id="datecheck"> 
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="check_in_time" name="check_in_time" value="11-09-2020" data-target="#datecheck" /> 
                <label class="input-group-addon" for="check_in_time"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">/

  $('#datecheck').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'ru'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Шаг первый

```
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['ru'] = {
        days: ["Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"],
        daysShort: ["Вск", "Пнд", "Втр", "Срд", "Чтв", "Птн", "Суб"],
        daysMin: ["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"],
        months: ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
        monthsShort: ["Янв", "Фев", "Мар", "Апр", "Май", "Июн", "Июл", "Авг", "Сен", "Окт", "Ноя", "Дек"],
        today: "Сегодня",
        clear: "Очистить",
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        titleFormat: "MM yyyy", /* Leverages same syntax as 'format' */
        weekStart: 0
    };
```

Шаг второй

```
   $('#datecheck').datetimepicker({
       language: 'ru'
   });
```

[Документация](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html?highlight=locale)